# how to find a particular div element with the help of .find selector and $(this)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I need to find a class  **.bar-steps** and then append the div under it. Below is the code that I have used:

**.js**

```
$(".priority-timeline").each(function (ind, elem) {
    var prioData = ko.dataFor($(elem)[0]);
    if (IsValidPriority(prioData, false)) {
        DrawSPPriorityTimeLine($(this), prioData);            
    }
});


function DrawSPPriorityTimeLine(currentElem, priorityObj) {

var activityTotalMonth = [0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8];    

$.each(activityTotalMonth, function (i, v) {
    var div = $('<div>');//.addClass('counts');
    currentElem.find('.bar-steps').append(div);
});
}
```

**Partial View**

```
<div class="priority-timeline" data-bind="foreach:MemberSupportPrioritySlot">
<div class="timeline-list">
    <div class="timeline-list-items">
        <h6 data-bind="text:hasValue(Title())?Title():'&nbsp;'"></h6>
        <div class="timeline-bar">
            <div data-bind="foreach:UpcomingActivities()">
                <div class="priority-icon completed" style="left: auto;">
                    @*<img src="service-plan/image/img_2.png" alt="">*@
                    <div class="detail-popup">
                        <strong data-bind="text:Title()"></strong>
                        <p data-bind="text:Description()">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bar-steps" style="width: 378px; left: 0px"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to find the class **bar-steps**, and honestly my element does not recognize it. What am I missing.

Any help with be appreciated.

Comment: What does IsValidPriority do? Can you show the code for this? Also it seems like you are receiving a DOM element, finding it with jQuery and then getting the DOM element out of jQuery again, why are you doing this?

Comment: I am able to solve the issue that I faced. Thanks everyone for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  $(".priority-timeline").each(function (ind, elem) {
    var prioData = ko.dataFor($(elem)[0]);
    if (IsValidPriority(prioData, false)) {
        DrawSPPriorityTimeLine($(this), prioData);            
    }
});


function DrawSPPriorityTimeLine(currentElem, priorityObj) {

var activityTotalMonth = [0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8];    

$.each(activityTotalMonth, function (i, v) {
    var div = $('<div>');//.addClass('counts');
    $(currentElem).find('.bar-steps').append(div);
});
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tp8jddcn/2/

Comment: how will the currentelem find the class when its the object? 
It is throwing error as u suggested

Comment: This is what I have written in my question. I used the same thing

Comment: you want to append one div or 8?

Comment: I want to append 8 divs

Comment: Appearantly, this fiddle is working, correct? So is there anything else in your code that prevents the piece of javascript from running. Do you have any javascript errors?

Does the code ever hit your `DrawSPPriorityTimeLine`, or is `IsValidPriority(prioData, false)` ever `true`?

Comment: well, my code do hit both the methods and I am successful in debugging as well. I exactly dont know what problem is there and why respective divs are not showing...

Comment: Wait so the problem is that your divs aren't showing? You do know that your code is adding empty divs? Have you looked in your dev tools to see if the divs are actually there? If there are actually there then what are the contents and what should their contents be?

Comment: I have used knockout binding foreach with MemberSupportPrioritySlot for the div class "priority-timeline". When i remove this binding my code works and it does have values as well. I have checked it with the text binding and  it successfully displays the value. I dont know what is missing